# Eclipse doesn't recognize new files created by others in the repository

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse 4.7.2, and imported my local repository to the workspace.
The problem is when others push to the remote repository with some newly created files and I fetch them to the local by `git fetch&&merge`.
I check my local repository by terminal and confirm that new commits are successfully imported. But Eclipse doesn't recognize the new file, and many lines using the new class are regarded as errors. (New commits on the existing files are recognized with no problem)

I always use git command on terminal. Maybe Egit can solve this but I don't know the proper setting.
How can I make Eclipse recognize a new file?

Comment: Refresh. I don’t recall the keyboard shortcut, F5?

Comment: Also check the Workspace and git preference pages for automatic refresh settings.

Answer (score 1):

Following Dave's comment, I found `right-click on project > Refresh` worked. Thanks!